# Oracle: Using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with RETURNING INTO

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure that does a validation and inserts a record in a table. The procedure is breaking right after the `INSERT` statement when I try the following code:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SOME_STRNG || ' returning SOME_ID into :NEW_ID' returning into V_TRGT_ID;
```

I am trying to execute my `INSERT` statement which is stored in `V_SOME_STRNG` and assign the new record's ID to `V_TRGT_ID`. However, I am running into the following error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to repeat the `returning into` part, you need a `using` clause for your bind variable:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SOME_STRNG || ' returning SOME_ID into :NEW_ID' using out V_TRGT_ID;
```

Demo using a basic trigger to provide the ID:

```
create table t42 (some_id number, dummy varchar2(1));
create sequence s42 start with 42;
create trigger tr42 before insert on t42 for each row
begin
  :new.some_id := s42.nextval;
end;
/

set serveroutput on
declare
  v_some_strng varchar2(200) := 'insert into t42 (dummy) values (''X'')';
  v_trgt_id number;
begin
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SOME_STRNG || ' returning SOME_ID into :NEW_ID' using out V_TRGT_ID; 
  dbms_output.put_line('Returned ID: ' || v_trgt_id);
end;
/
```

which shows:

```
Returned ID: 42

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

You can only use `returning into` with the `insert .. values ...` pattern, not with `insert ... select ...`; so for instance changing the code above to use;

```
  v_some_strng varchar2(200) := 'insert into t42 (dummy) select ''X'' from dual';
```

will get the error you originally reported:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at line 6
```

Comment: That did not work as well. It works fine when I `EXECUTE` a `SELECT statement` after my `INSERT statement` to get the required value; but as a requirement, I have to use this method.

Comment: I've shown it working. What do you mean by "did not work"? What happens?

Comment: Procedure still breaks with the same error being logged.

Comment: Then maybe the problem is somewhere else in `v_some_strng`, or somewhere else in the block; or it's a version issue. I tested this in 11gR2; which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 12c, could that be the problem?

Comment: @samg no,that's not the case(the version 12c ). Works properly on DB with version 12.1.0.2.0.

Comment: @samg - you didn't show your insert statement; are you doing `insert ... select ...` rather than `insert .. values ...`? You can't use it with the `select` version; see the syntax diagram [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423).

Comment: @AlexPoole - you are right and I did some research which shows that I can use `RETURNING INTO` with the use of `VALUES`. However, due to the complexity of my `INSERT STATEMENT` my procedure keeps breaking.

Answer (score 0):

While you don't need to use `returning into` part, the OP problem most likely results from an error in the not shown content of the `V_SOME_STRNG` variable. Because you definitely can use `returning into` with `execute immediate`. Here is an example strait from [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm):

```sql
sql_stmt := 'UPDATE emp SET sal = 2000 WHERE empno = :1 RETURNING sal INTO :2';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING emp_id RETURNING INTO salary;
```

I stress the point again: **it works**. So if you have any troubles here check you dynamically generated SQL statement more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

My test_queries table consist of 2 columns:fid and query_text.I want insert new row. And I return fid I inserted because I use it next question. But the code give me error .

select max(a.fid) into max_fid from test_queries a;
execute immediate 'insert into test_queries values (:1,:2) returning fid into :a' using max_fid+1,query_text,c;